# "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" for mixed case table and columns

Tags: oracle, toad, ora-00942, quoted-identifier

TOAD gives "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" when updating mixed case tables or columns. For update I do not write any queries, I am trying to update data on grid (data tab). For upper case tables and columns it updates sucessfully. For some reason TOAD generates query without double quotations. Are there any workarounds for this issue?

Comment: Are you bound to using Toad? What queries do you want to generate exactly? What tool of Toad are you using (SQL worksheet, and when you press CTRL-ENTER your query does not work?)

Comment: @archstanton whats the actual SQL?

Comment: updated question. I am trying to update data on grid, not by writing query.

Comment: The best solution is **never, ever, create cased object names. Only ever use the default**. If you don't it only leads to problems, as you're discovering. I know nothing about Toad, so I can't help you with your specific problem.

Comment: @Benoit - TOAD is so very nice.. that's why :)

Answer (score 3):

There is an option in TOAD to double-quote object names. Go into the View menu, choose TOAD Options, select the Oracle/General entry, and change the Double Quote Object Names to "All".

Comment: I'm using 9.5.0.31 version. I couldnt find such an option.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure when it was introduced. I have version 10.5.